# Check if an app can read certain folders

Tags: command-line, permission

AFAIK MacOS restricts newly installed apps from reading many folders without user permission. I know these permission are listed under System Preferences->Privacy->Files and Folders

But, is there a way I can verify these permissions are actually enforced? Like can I open a shell with the same permissions as a specific app? Kind of like `su - nameofapp`?

I ask because I just installed the Amazon Kindle App from the MacOS App Store. I looked in `~/Library/Containers/com.amazon.Kindle/Data` and see this

```
❯ pwd
/Users/gregg/Library/Containers/com.amazon.Kindle/Data
❯ ls -l
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gregg  staff    19 Jan  7 21:01 Desktop -> ../../../../Desktop
drwx------   2 gregg  staff    64 Jan  7 21:01 Documents
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gregg  staff    21 Jan  7 21:01 Downloads -> ../../../../Downloads
drwx------  33 gregg  staff  1056 Jan  7 21:19 Library
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gregg  staff    18 Jan  7 21:01 Movies -> ../../../../Movies
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gregg  staff    17 Jan  7 21:01 Music -> ../../../../Music
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gregg  staff    20 Jan  7 21:01 Pictures -> ../../../../Pictures
drwx------   2 gregg  staff    64 Jan  7 21:01 SystemData
drwx------   2 gregg  staff    64 Jan  7 21:01 tmp
```

Apparently the app has made links to a bunch of folders. How can I know if the app is actually prevented from accessing those folders via the links? I have not given the app any permissions and would just like to verify that these links are not away around the permissions.

Answer (score 2):

## macOS App Sandbox

`~/Library/Containers` is created by macOS and not the application. Sandboxed applications are effectively `chroot`'d into their container. You can learn more in Apple's [App Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html) documentation.

Sandboxed applications have a `com.apple.security.app-sandbox` entitlement set to `true`.

You can view the entitlements of an application using the command line tool `codesign`:

```
codesign --display --entitlements=- /Applications/Safari.app
```

There is no way to run a shell script using the rights of another application.

macOS's sandboxing approach requires that you [trust](https://saagarjha.com/blog/2020/05/20/mac-app-store-sandbox-escape/) Apple's implementation.